# Replace a part of a string with mySQL - how to remove middle initial from first name field

Tags: mysql

I feel like I'm missing something easy here but...

If I have the following data in a mySQL table (users.fName):

```
--------------    
| Jason M.   |
--------------
| Eric       |
--------------
| Tim S      |
--------------
| Peggy Sue  |
--------------
```

And I want to end up with:

```
--------------    
| Jason      |
--------------
| Eric       |
--------------
| Tim        |
--------------
| Peggy Sue  |
--------------
```

I figure I have to eliminate the . after Jason M. (which I can do easily enough with `UPDATE users SET fName = REPLACE(fName, ".", "");` ) but how can I eliminate the M and S but leave Sue?

I know `SUBSTRING_INDEX` can get parts of the field and I can use something like `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(fName, ' ', -1), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fName, ' ', -1)) FROM users` to get the lenght of the second part of the string but I'm not sure how to update the field to the first part of the string only of the second part is only one character long.

**UPDATE**

The answer form @Dan got me what I needed once I made one change to his query.  The updated query is:

```
SELECT `fName`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fName`, ' ', -1) AS MiddleInitial
    FROM `users`
    WHERE TRIM(`fName`) LIKE '%.' 
        AND length(`fName`)> 4 
        OR length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fName`, ' ', -1)) = 1;
```

The last `AND` becomes an `OR` and all worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar situation and used a where clause to only select names with a space somewhere in the field.  Further, I checked that what I expected to be a middle initial was indeed only one characters long with `length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(First, ' ', -1)) = 1`.

```
SELECT `First`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`First`, ' ', -1) AS MiddleInitial
FROM YourTable
WHERE trim(`First`) LIKE '%.' AND length(`First`)> 4 AND 
length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`First`, ' ', -1)) = 1;
```

Look over the results of the select before running the update but this should limit your query  to only initials and leave names like Billy Bob alone.

Comment: your query works once I change WHERE trim(`First`) LIKE '%.' AND length(`First`)> 4 AND to WHERE trim(`First`) LIKE '%.' AND length(`First`)> 4 OR

Answer (score 0):

You can use an User Defined Function like [UDF](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp) and the use a Regex for doing it.